# How to implement ParallelForEach<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action<TSource> body)?

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to implement `Parallel.ForEach<TSource>` (with parameters pointed out above), but I have no idea how to use `ParallelOptions` - how to "handle" it and what it will change

It is the clear body of my function

```cs
public static void ParallelForEachWithOptions<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action<TSource> body)
{

}
```

Comment: Are you re-implementing this yourself?

Comment: Yes,and i must re-implement this depending on ParallelOptions' MaxDegreeOfParallelism's value

Comment: I guess reimplementing it would be a good learning experience for a hobby or academic project. For commercial software, no way should you be re-implementing this. Hopefully you are just going to wrap the existing TPL method and maybe shuffle around some parameters. Are you?

Comment: I am going to re-implement this to understand the structure and the logic of this method,and,in this case,to work with threads

Comment: In my implementing i must change some logic depending on ParallelOptions' MaxDegreeOfParallelism(change the number of threads working parallel)

Comment: @APapyan instead of re-implementing PLINQ, read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/data-parallelism-task-parallel-library) and source code. Parellel/PLINQ are meant for data parallelism, not for spawning threads. They partition the data and feed each partition to a separate worker task. The MaxDOP option affects the number of partitions. Other parameters affect dynamic vs static partitioning and load balancing

Comment: Each worker task works on its partition *synchronously*, which avoids the synchronization overhead needed if all workers had to pull data from a single input queue. This means that the worker can use a CPU at 100%. It also means it can *starve* other applications. That's why another option allows recycling tasks after N iterations, to give other threads/applications a chance to run.